# jQuery removing an element and its sibling

Tags: jquery, siblings

I have a table that has an even number of rows.

Odd rows are visible and have a delete button in them, even rows are hidden.

Delete should remove a pair, the odd row and the hidden even row.

The following only removes the odd row. How can I remove the odd row **and** the next sibling?

```
$('deleteButton').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.remove().next('tr').remove();
});
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) jQuery method:

```
$tr.next('tr').addBack().remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, It is very useful & addBack() is new for me :)

Comment: @A.Wolff: This is removing the current closest tr also. How can we preserve not removing the current row?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `sibling` first as removing the source `row` first will cause an error when trying to access the `sibling` of removed row.

```
$('deleteButton').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.next('tr').remove();
    $tr.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,It will work,

```
$('deleteButton').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.next('tr').remove();
    $tr.remove();
});
```